# move the first word to the last position in Java

Tags: java

How can I make `Jave is the language` to be `Is the language Java`
Here is my code, but I think there are some problems here.

```
public class Lab042{
    public static final String testsentence = "Java is the language";
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String rephrased = rephrase( testsentence);
        System.out.println("The sentence:"+testsentence);
        System.out.println("was rephrased to:"+rephrased);
    }

    public static String rephrase(String testsentence) {
        int index = testsentence.indexOf (' ');
        char c = testsentence.charAt(index+1);
        String start = String.valueOf(c).toUpperCase();
        start += testsentence.substring(index+2);
        start += " ";
        String end = testsentence.substring(0,index);
        String rephrase = start + end;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a `StringBuilder` in `rephrase()`.

Comment: Leo, If there is a correct answer here, please upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning the new phrase. At the bottom of your method rephrase(), put this:

```
return rephrase;
```

Answer (score 2):

use String.split

```
String testsentence = "Java is the language";
String [] arr = testsentence.split (" ");
String str = "";

for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i)
   str += arr[i];

return str + arr[0];
```

For a real world program use StringBuilder rather than concatenating the Strings though

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `rephrase()` method as follows. It is more readable and clear.

```
public static String rephrace(String testsentence) {
    //Separate the first word and rest of the sentence
    String [] parts = testsentence.split(" ", 2);
    String firstWord = parts[0];
    String rest = parts[1];

    //Make the first letter of rest capital
    String capitalizedRest = rest.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + rest.substring(1);

    return capitalizedRest + " " + firstWord;
}
```

I did not include validation error checks. But in a production code you should validate the array and string lengths before you access them using the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prograProj3
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputText, firstWord2, firstWord;
        System.out.println("Enter a line of text. No punctuation please.");
        inputText = keyboard.nextLine();
        firstWord = inputText.substring(0, inputText.indexOf(' '));
        inputText = (inputText.replaceFirst(firstWord, "")).trim();
        inputText = ((inputText.substring(0, 1))).toUpperCase() + inputText.substring(1);
        System.out.println(inputText + " " + firstWord);
    }
}
```